# Does anyone know if there's a term for eyes with long, tapered inner corners?

Tags: terminology

I'm not talking about epicanthic folds or monolids, nor even upturned eyes. I'm trying to describe a particular eye shape, and I've pored over dozens of cosmetic sites and discovered many templates that share the same terminology, but this particular trait is absent. I couldn't find any mention of it, although it seems to be fairly common.

You know how we talk about "crow's feet" when we're describing lines under the outer corner of the eye? Well, I'm talking about eyes with a "crow's beak," eyes with elongated inner corners, almost like a bird dipping its neck to the ground. If anyone is aware of a more flattering way to describe this particular eye shape, I'd very much like to learn it. A handful of cosmetic templates appear to describe this shape as "drooping eyes", but it seems like there's too much potential for confusion with droopy eyelids to describe them in this way.

Off the cuff, Angelina Jolie and Gemma Ward provide some of the clearest examples of this trait. It doesn't appear to be an exclusive feature of "almond-shaped eyes", though I see it much more often in people with this eye shape. But a search for "round eyes" also generates people with the same trait--I'll post an example below for reference. Finally, Lenore from Castlevania is also drawn with eyes like this, although the corners tend to be shaded in; I wanted to post an image, but it wouldn't take.

See how Angelina's eyes have long, tapered inner corners?:

[image: See how Angelina's eyes have long, tapered inner corners?]

This doesn't appear to be a feature exclusive to almond-shaped eyes. Note the same swoop-necked shape. It's a tricky thing to describe, because the right eye almost looks like an epicanthal fold, and I think she's accentuating this with eyeliner and thick, swoopy lashes :

[image: This doesn't appear to be a feature exclusive to almond-shaped eyes. Note the same swoop-necked shape. It's a tricky thing to describe, because the right eye almost looks like an epicanthal fold, and I think she's accentuating this with eyeliner and thick, swoopy lashes.]

Comment: I think you'll get more mileage out of describing it "... almost like a bird dipping its neck to the ground", than just calling it by a clinical word no one is familiar with.

Comment: @wetcircuit surely, the use of a clinical term would help OP's audience become familiar with little known but cool words?

Comment: I guess I wouldn't mind a clinical term, although you may have the right of it, wetcircuit. It depends on how obscure and clinical we're talking. The only time I've ever seen "epicanthic fold" work in a sentence was in a Takeshi Kovacs novel, and Richard Morgan was deliberately applying this description through the lens of someone who sees all human bodies as a form of apparel.

Comment: Image descriptions only exist for people with screen readers, so I've pulled them into the body of the post. The images seemed kinda confusing without the descriptions.